# PHP WoW Battle.net Armory API library: Pulling data from cache in db

Tags: php, mysql, caching, blob, world-of-warcraft

I am using this library: https://sourceforge.net/p/wowarmoryapi/home/Home/ which seriously lacks documentation. The forums there are mostly unanswered.

I've been able to successfully pull data from battle net's armory, specifically guild information. It is then stored in the **wa_guilds** table as a large blob in a row called **Data**. From there I'm unsure how to pull it and display it. I've tried the code below and about 100 different variations of that as well as unserialize but I'm too inexperienced. This is just past my level of knowledge.

My Error: **Notice: Undefined index: object**
I've tried name, level, rank

New error caused by **print $roster->character;**:
"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

My code:

```
<?php
include('_inc.php'); // shh I'm hunting wabbits
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "")
    or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($conn, "wow")
    or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Data FROM wa_guilds") or die(mysql_error());

//echo $data;

print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $data, MYSQLI_BOTH )) 
{   
    $roster = json_decode($info[0]);
    print $roster->character;
} 
print "</table>";

//$array = explode(',', $data);
//echo $array[0];

?>
```

It looks like a popular library so I'm hoping someone has experience with it.

Some data from var_dump:

> array(2) { [0]=> string(100000)
>   "{"lastModified":1367433943000,"name":"Teh
>   Fail","realm":"Zul'jin","battlegroup":"Ruin","level":25,"side":1,"achievementPoints":1195,
>   [{"character":{"name":"Mundi","realm":"Zul'jin","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":8,"race":8,"gender":0,"level":85,"achievementPoints":12855,"thumbnail":"zuljin/65/3357249-avatar.jpg","guild":"Teh
>   Fail","spec":{"name":"Fire","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-mage-fire","icon":"spell_fire_firebolt02","description":"Ignite
>   enemies with balls of fire and combustive
>   flames.","order":1}},"rank":3},{"character":{"name":"Kekeke","realm":"Zul'jin","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":4,"race":8,"gender":0,"level":85,"achievementPoints":11345,"thumbnail":"zuljin/76/3359564-avatar.jpg","guild":"Teh
>   Fail","spec":{"name":"Combat","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-rogue-combat","icon":"ability_backstab","description":"A
>   swashbuckler who uses agility and guile to stand toe-to-toe with
>   enemies.","order":1}},"rank":3},{"character":{"name":"Benth","realm":"Zul'jin","battlegroup":"Ruin","class":9,"race":5,"gender":0,"level":90,"achievementPoints":13165,"thumbnail":"zuljin/252/3364348-avatar.jpg","guild":"Teh
>   Fail","spec":{"name":"Destruction","role":"DPS","backgroundImage":"bg-warlock-destruction","icon":"spell_shadow_rainoffire","description":"A
>   master of chaos who calls down fire to burn and demolish
>   enemies.","order":2}},"rank":3}

Edit:
**Changed mysqli database connection lines to PDO and all is well.**

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($info)` to see what's actually in there?

Comment: @andrewsi I get this: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: Huh. mysqli_fetch_array should be returning an array, not a mysqli_result object - where did you add the `var_dump($info)` line? Before, after, or in the middle of your while loop?

Comment: @andrewsi oops! I put in the loops this time and got a wall of text back. It doesn't fit here, I'll add it up top.

Comment: It looks like it's (er) JSON encoded - you just need to decode it, I think.

Comment: @andrewsi inside my loop I added `$roster = json_decode($info);
 print $roster->{'character'};
 //var_dump($info);`
_json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in_

Comment: You currently have an array of two items - try using $info[0] instead?

Comment: @andrewsi same error :( 
It did change in the var_dump though. it just removed "array(2) { [0]=>"

Comment: This is what happens when my caffeine levels run too low. Have you tried using `json_decode($info[0])`? I think you have a two-item array, and the first item is your encoded string.

Comment: lol good ol' caffeine. Yeah that's what I tried. Same error it seems.

Comment: @andrewsi I'm not really sure why, but once I changed from mysqli to PDO it started working. Thank you for the help! I learned some new tricks thanks to you. :)

Comment: You're right - that is terribly confusing. I'm glad you got it working in the end, though!